# EEPROM corruption with heavy VCC interferences

Tags: emc, eeprom

I have an EEPROM memory ([24LC01B](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/24AA01#document-table) on a board used with *severe* electrical noise.

Severe as in the external watchdog needs to reset everything (it's doing its job, correctly). Everything restarts correctly but *occasionally* the first four memory bytes get corrupted (more precisely, erased to FF)

There is one [appnote](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/Flash-Memory-Corruption) stating that heavy supply noise could cause the issue and they recommend to keep the memory pointer away from the data in case a spurious write cycle is issued. I suppose that these I2C parts keep their pointer to zero since it's the only one area I ever found corrupted (maybe it works with a 32 bits architecture inside, it isn't stated).

The memory is actually mostly in read operation since it contains constant data (serial number, calibrations, that kind of stuff) so I'm quite sure it's not an interrupted write.

As a workaround I'm simply staying away from cells 0-3 (and storing data in duplicate with a checksum!) but I'm worried. In your experience does the ~WP pin helps? Should I simply cut off power when I'm not using it? Any other ideas?

Comment: IMO, you should fix the EMC issue first if the WDT is being used measurably. You could also use the write inhibit function on some EEPROMs, avoid using the first bytes, make the EEPROM self-repairing, but the EMC issue sounds critical.

Comment: +1 on @SpehroPefhany, don't band-aid, fix the root cause. What does your layout and decoupling situation look like?

Comment: I know that EMC is the root cause (in fact I can see the noise in air *and* on the power lines) but, as usual, shielding and filtering are expensive and they want to do it cheap. As in industrial reliability with chinese junk price :(

Comment: The rule of thumb is to never use external memories in noisy (industrial/automotive etc) applications to begin with. Use on-chip memory in the MCU instead.

Comment: Although if the problem is confirmed to be surges in the supply during read rather than the I2C bus picking up noise, a sufficiently large supercap that discharges to your CMOS levels slower than a complete eeprom erase/write cycle might solve a lot of problems.